# Setting ActionLink url using javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can we set the url(Action, controller and query string) using javascript in mvc.

Please suggest.

Thank you,

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this. You may find it useful.

http://www.campusmvp.net/blog/changing-script-variables-into-a-url-action-or-an-html-actionlink